# UITabelViewCell is still highlighted after I go to other view controller and comeback

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

`UITableViewCell` that has `UINavigationController` embedded is still highlighted when I pressed it to go to other `ViewController`.

Also, it is still highlighted if I use gesture to come back.

Can you please tell me how to make it unhighlighted when I come back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method add:

```
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```